# Masking out areas for a value range

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I would like to remove areas which are less than (mean value)*0.8 and the (mean value)*1.2 and would like to keep rest of the data. While trying different things my code became much more complicated then I was expected and doing the exact opposite thing I want to and only keeping values within this range. Can you help me to solve this please.

```
var DatasettoMask = Dataset.multiply(0.01)
var masktest = DatasettoMask.gte(SpatialMean.multiply(0.80)).and(Dataset.lte(SpatialMean.multiply(1.2)))
var DatasetMasked = masktest.updateMask(masktest).multiply(DatasettoMask)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the condition a bit more readable by using `expression()` and simplify the way you use the mask.

```
var masktest = ee.Image().expression(
  'i >= mean * 0.8 and i <= mean * 1.2', 
  {
    i: DatasettoMask,
    mean: SpatialMean
  }
)
var DatasetMasked = DatasettoMask.updateMask(masktest)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/acecd6dd0e18719d165f512124db439b